# ReactJS ES2015 Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm learning it based on ES2015.  Most examples are ES5.  My problem seems to be rendering child components.

My child component is a TextField

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TextField extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      customer: {
        custno: props.customer.custno
      }
    };
  }  

  render() {
      if(this.props.displayMode) {
        return <span>{this.props.custno}</span>
      }
      return <input type="text" {...this.props} />
  }
}

export default TextField;
```

My parent components is called AddressBox and will contain many of the child controls.  If displayMode is true, then it should render a SPAN but if it is false, it should render a form control.

The address box code is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextField} from '../textfield/textfield.js';

class AddressBox extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      customer: {
        custno: ""
      }
    };
    this.onCustomerNumberChange = this.onCustomerNumberChange.bind(this);
  }  

  onCustomerNumberChange(event) {
    const customer = this.state.customer;
    customer.custnumber = event.target.value;
    this.setState({customer: customer});
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="addressbox">
          <h1>Address Box</h1>
          <label>Customer Number:</label>
          <TextField value={this.state.customer.custno} onChange={this.onCustomerNumberChange} />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

AddressBox.defaultProps= {
  customer: {
    name: "",
    custnumber: ""
  }
}

export default AddressBox;
```

When I try to render these controls, I get the following error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `AddressBox`.
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of
>   `AddressBox`.

All of the examples I can find are using the previous React.createClass method.  Can anyone tell me why the TextField is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I was using the wrong Import syntax.

I was using

```
import {TextField} from '../textfield/textfield';
```

when I should have used:

```
import TextField from '../textfield/textfield';
```